# Porque obtengo este error al autenticarme?

Tags: reactjs, tokens, next.js, auth

Estoy usando NextJs con la librería next-auth y cuando implemento la función `signIn` y la configuro no puedo autenticarme y me envía a la página `404` de next y en consola obtengo este error:

```
error - ./node_modules/next-auth/providers/email.js:8:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'nodemailer'
null
```

===================

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';
import classes from './auth-form.module.css';

async function createUser(email, password) {
  const response = await fetch('/api/auth/signup', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });

  const data = await response.json();

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(data.message || 'Something went wrong!');
  }

  return data;
}

function AuthForm() {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);

  const emailInputRef = useRef();
  const passwordInputRef = useRef();

  function switchAuthModeHandler() {
    setIsLogin(prevState => !prevState);
  }

  async function submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;

    // optional: Add validation

    if (isLogin) {
      const result = await signIn('credentials', {
        redirect: false,
        email: enteredEmail,
        password: enteredPassword,
      });

      console.log(result);
    } else {
      try {
        const response = await createUser(enteredEmail, enteredPassword);
        console.log(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className={classes.auth}>
      <h1>{isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Sign Up'}</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className={classes.control}>
          <label htmlFor="email">Your Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" required ref={emailInputRef} />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.control}>
          <label htmlFor="password">Your Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            required
            ref={passwordInputRef}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <button>{isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Create Account'}</button>
          <button
            type="button"
            className={classes.toggle}
            onClick={switchAuthModeHandler}
          >
            {isLogin ? 'Create new account' : 'Login with existing account'}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}

export default AuthForm;
```

Comment: El error dice que te hace falta el modulo `nodemailer`. ¿Instalaste la dependencia?, ¿Cuál es el código donde hacer el `import` del modulo?

Comment: pero no uso en ningún momento ese módulo en el proyecto

Comment: Deberías intentar instalar la librería. https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/pull/2168 Mira lo que habla ese issue en GitHub.

Comment: Solucionado! Estaba usando una configuración de la versión anterior cuando en realidad había instalado la última . Gracias!